# Visual Studio 2017 RC4 Webdeploy results in ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: webdeploy, visual-studio-2017

Tried everything. Deploying same type of web project (Net.Core 1.1) with VS2015 at the very same location using exactly same parameters works without any problems.

Is there any known issue with release RC.4+26206?

This what my server log says:

```
IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED

Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server connection. Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or Application' task to be able to connect.

Process:WMSvc
User=sludr
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Found a solution. Same reason as documented here: [.net core web deploy requires admin permissions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5626/net-core-web-deploy-requires-admin-permissions.html), so VS2017 requires right now a windows account of group Administrators to publish net core projects.

Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The official VS 2017 RTW still has this bug.